# Why do GL_POINTs' relative size get bigger the further you are?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glpointsize

I am drawing a set of GL_POINT in my particle system in my game with a certain point size that works for when the player is close to the particle emitter, but when you get furhter from it the particles seem to get bigger. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here you have to pictures to support my question:
The first one is from far, the particle emitter is the green/blue square in the left side of the screen, between the two big icebergs. The second one is closer and the points have now the correct size and interpolate it correctly too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can we get a sample from the shader that you are using to display the particles ?